# Accessing PHP $_SESSION in FeatureContext file

Tags: php, laravel, selenium-webdriver, behat, mink

I have a PHP file that generates a dynamic payment URL and saves it in `$_SESSION['userDetails']`. Now, I want to `read/access` that `$_SESSION['userDetails']` value in my `FeatureContext.php` file under `Behat`. Can anyone please guide me on how to work on it?

I tried the following code, but it gives me Null for `$cururl` and some array for the `$session`...

```
use Behat\Mink\Driver\Selenium2Driver;
use Behat\Mink\Session;

class FeatureContext extends Context implements BehatContext, SnippetAcceptingContext
{
    protected $session;

    public function __construct()
    {
        if (defined('APP_MODE') && APP_MODE === 'DEV') {
            $baseUrl = 'http://localhost';
        } else {
            $baseUrl = 'http://MAINSITEurl';
        }

        parent::__construct($baseUrl);

        // ensure request factory is available
        $this->jsonUtility = JsonUtility::getInstance();
        $this->requestFactory = RequestFactory::getInstance();
        $this->arrayUtility = ArrayUtility::getInstance();
    }

    public function iAmRedirectedToPaymentPage()
    {
        $driver = new \Behat\Mink\Driver\Selenium2Driver('firefox');

        $session = new \Behat\Mink\Session($driver);

        // start the session
        $session->start();
        $cururl = $session->getCurrentUrl();
        var_dump($cururl);
        var_dump($session);
        die();
    }
}
```

Getting this as output for `var_dump($session)`

```
class Behat\Mink\Session#946 (3) {
  private $driver =>
  class Behat\Mink\Driver\Selenium2Driver#967 (8) {
    private $started =>
    bool(true)
    private $webDriver =>
    class WebDriver\WebDriver#944 (1) {
      protected $url =>
      string(28) "http://localhost:4444/wd/hub"
    }
    private $browserName =>
    string(7) "firefox"
    private $desiredCapabilities =>
    array(9) {
      'browserName' =>
      string(7) "firefox"
      'version' =>
      string(1) "9"
```

How to get `$_SESSION['userDetails']` value in `Behat`??

Comment: *it gives me Null for $cururl and some array for the $session...* What do you expect `$_SESSION` to be? https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php

Comment: well, I just want to access whatever value is there in `$_SESSION['userDetails']` , in my Behat Context file.

Comment: But `$session` is an instance of `Behat\Mink\Session`, not your regular `$_SESSION`. Read the docs for it and it should probably be a little clearer: http://mink.behat.org/en/latest/guides/session.html You've probably missed a `visit()` to the correct URL.